# Failed to run a Junit test

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have build webservice code. In which I am adding a Junit test case for a restController.

I tired the command as

```
mvn -Dtest="completed package"+classname test
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) on project isi-service: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) on project iamsi-service: No te
sts were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
```

My class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ITokenServiceHandlerBase  {

    @InjectMocks
    private ITokenServiceHandlerBase   iTokenServiceHandlerBase  ;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(iTokenServiceHandlerBase )
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void handleGet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(Constants.IM_TOKEN_API_V1)
        ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Using Intellij run test menu:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe"
>   -Dvisualvm.id=21230012706744 -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2018.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=60543:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2018.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2018.1.4\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\com\pearson\glp\client-crosscutting\0.33.1\client-crosscutting-0.33.1.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\com\pearson\platform\common\0.33.4\common-0.33.4.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\com\pearson\platform\utils\0.33.4\utils-0.33.4.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.15.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.15.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.15.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.10\swagger-annotations-1.5.10.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\ant-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\ant-antlr-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\ant-junit-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\ant-launcher-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\bsf-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\gpars-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-ant-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-bsf-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-console-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-docgenerator-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-groovydoc-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-groovysh-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-jmx-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-json-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-jsr223-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-nio-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-servlet-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-sql-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-swing-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-templates-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-test-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-testng-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\groovy-xml-2.4.15.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\ivy-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\jansi-1.11.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\jcommander-1.47.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\jline-2.12.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\jsp-api-2.0.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\jsr166y-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\multiverse-core-0.7.0.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\qdox-1.12.1.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\testng-6.8.13.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2\Downloads\apache-groovy-sdk-2.4.15\groovy-2.4.15\lib\xstream-1.4.10.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\4.3.15.RELEASE\spring-test-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\org\powermock\powermock-core\1.6.6\powermock-core-1.6.6.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\1.5.11.RELEASE\spring-boot-test-1.5.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-contract-verifier\1.2.3.RELEASE\spring-cloud-contract-verifier-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\1.10.19\mockito-core-1.10.19.jar;C:\Users\yogendra.singh2.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar"
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4
>   com.platform.iam.servicehandler.ImTokenApiServiceHandlerBase,handleGet
>
> **Process finished with exit code 1 Class not found: "com.platform.iam.servicehandler.ImTokenApiServiceHandlerBase"Empty
>   test suite.**

Comment: Your class name is `ITokenServiceHandlerBase` but the error is for `ImTokenApiServiceHandlerBase` - typo?

Answer (score 0):

Maven can have an issue recognizing JUnit tests during its build process because of the Class name itself.

Try to rename your class with a suffix of "Test", so something like "iTokenServiceHandlerBaseTest".